# Problem creating a CTE in MySQL Workbench. What is the syntax error here?

Tags: mysql-workbench

This is what I wrote but I'm getting syntax error.

with popvsvac (continent, date, location, population, new_vaccination, sum(covid_vaccinations.new_vaccinations) over (partition by coviddeaths.location order by coviddeaths.location, coviddeaths.date) as "Rolling Count")

as

(

select coviddeaths.continent, coviddeaths.date, coviddeaths.location, coviddeaths.population, covid_vaccinations.new_vaccinations,

sum(covid_vaccinations.new_vaccinations) over (partition by coviddeaths.location order by coviddeaths.location, coviddeaths.date) as "Rolling Count"

from coviddeaths

join covid_vaccinations

on coviddeaths.location = covid_vaccinations.location

and coviddeaths.date = covid_vaccinations.date

)

select * from popvsvac;

I was hoping to get a rolling count with the partition by clause. I achieved that but then i need to get divide rollingcount by population. Which is why I wanted the CTE.